# The comprehensive list of the Android permission with corresponding class

Tags: java, android

My boss wants to know about the comprehensive list of the java class using some Android permissions such as `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, CAMERA`. However, I cannot find the whole list of the java class using these permissions. I have to check the class I used on the Android developer website to identify the corresponding `user-permissions`. I tried to read the Caution: info in the official [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions) website 
Following the info from the Android developer, it should be possible to find out all the java classes using the specific user permission (e.g. `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` using `ConnectivityManager` ) based on the `targetsdkversion` of the Android project. But I cannot find any further information about that. Does anyone know where I can get the list of that ?

Comment: Thank you for the improvement. I am newbie and learning the format now:)

Comment: out of curiosity - he wants this for what really? to make you busy?

Comment: He wants the list about how many java classes I used in the corresponding permission. I tried to find it out but I can't. May be it is not possible to find out the list but i have to give him the reason at least why I cannot find it out.